# A question about BMO functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $B$ be a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let
\begin{equation*}
\|f\|_{BMO}=\sup_{B}\frac{1}{|B|}
\int_{B}|f(x)-f_{B}|dx,
\end{equation*}
where
$$
f_{B}=\frac{1}{|B|} \int_{B} f(x)dx.
$$
Define
$$
BMO(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{ f\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^n) ~ : ~ \| f \|_{BMO} < \infty  \}.
$$

Claim: For all $r>0$, there exists $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$|B(x_0,r)|^{-1} \,\|f(\cdot)-f_{B(x_0,r)}\|_{L_{1}(B(x_0,r))} > \frac{\|f\|_{BMO}}{2}.$$

I need such a property. But i can not show that if it is valid or not?

My attempt: I use the property $\sup A=a\iff \forall \epsilon>0~~ \exists x_0\in A~~ x_0>a-\epsilon.$

Suppose $\|f\|_{BMO}>0$ and choose $\epsilon=\frac{\|f\|_{BMO}}{2}$ then we have there exist a ball $B_0$ such that
$$
|B_0|^{-1} \,\|f(\cdot)-f_{B_0}\|_{L_{1}(B_0)} > \frac{\|f\|_{BMO}}{2}.
$$
After that how can i continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true. Take $n=1$, $f= \chi_{(0,1)}$. Then certainly $\|f\|_{BMO}>0$.

Now let $r>1$, let $B$ be a ball with radius $r$ such that $|B\cap (0,1)| = \delta\in [0,1]$.
Then
$$
f_B = \frac \delta {2r}
$$
and
$$
\frac1{|B|}\int_\mathbb R| f-f_B|
=\frac1{2r}\left ((2r-\delta) \frac \delta {2r} + \delta (1- \frac \delta {2r}) \right) \le \frac1{2r}\left ( {2r} \frac \delta {2r} + \delta ) \right) \le \frac1r
$$
which tends to zero for $r\to\infty$.

So the claim is false for this particular function and sufficiently large $r$.